# How to find out which is the installation account for sharepoint 2010.

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I have a sharepoint site installed and configured on farm. I want to find out which is the account used [spinstall, the user has not used the naming conventions] to do the installation. Is there a way I can find that out?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Check the account under which the Central Administration web site's application pool is running

Answer (score 0):

JumpingThroughCode's answer would only be correct if they made the mistake of doing the installation with Farm Service account. The Farm Service account should be a low-privileged account that is the CA AppPool account and the Timer Service account. The Farm Admin, or Installer, account is a highly privileged account used to install the product and any updates, and is the initial Farm Administrator account.

I don't know of any way to reliably determine this via code - I've seen it suggested that this account would be the only one in both Farm Administrators and Managed Service Accounts, but it could have been removed from Farm Administrators.

I would recommend checking the installation logs in the 14/LOGS folder.